# Swipe to scroll horizontally

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have some cards in a div without layout-wrap. How can i scroll through this cards with swiping? is this achievable using ng-touch?

Also i want all cards to have the same height which is why i added `style="height: 90%"` to `md-card`. is this the right way to do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seq3s.jpg

```
<div layout="row">
    <div flex-sm="35" flex-md="20" flex="10" ng-repeat="img in images">
        <md-card style="height: 90%">
            <img ng-src="resources/images/{{img.src}}" class="md-card-image"
                 alt="{{img.title}}">
            <md-card-content>
                <span class="md-body-2">{{img.title}}</span>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't use angular material to much, but I think you have to wrapp it in an mdContent.

Comment: the code is a templateUrl. it is wrapped in a mdContent. <md-content><ng-view></ng-view></md-content>

Comment: You can scroll the card's? And in a touch device you can't?

Comment: Exactly. I can scroll using mouse but i cant using a touch device.

Comment: Strange, it should work on the device also. Idk then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use [md-swipe-right md-swipe-left](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/swipe)

**Controller:**

```
    $scope.onSwipeLeft = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped left!!');
    };
    $scope.onSwipeRight = function(ev) {
      alert('You swiped right!!');
    };
```

**HTML:**

```
<div layout="row">
    <div flex-sm="35" flex-md="20" flex="10" ng-repeat="img in images">
        <md-card style="height: 90%" md-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" >
            <img ng-src="resources/images/{{img.src}}" class="md-card-image"
                 alt="{{img.title}}">
            <md-card-content>
                <span class="md-body-2">{{img.title}}</span>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```